# Setting default values to appended text boxes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I am looking to pass a list of autocomplete values to text boxes that have been appended based on a specified number of units.

```
function getUnits() {
    var units = $("#units").val();
    if (units > 1){
    for (var count = 1; count < units-1; count++) {
        $("<input type='text' /><br>").appendTo("#left-col");
    }
    $("#left-col").append('<input type="text">');
}}

$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTagList)
      .getAvailableTags();
});

function buildTagList(availableTags) {
  $( '#med' ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
}
```

This is the code for appending the appropriate amount of text boxes based on the # of units.

```
function getAvailableTags() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("someID");
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("someSheet");
  var drug = s.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var headers = 1; 
  var tagColumn = 0; 

  var availableTags = [];
  for (var row=headers; row < drug.length; row++) {
    availableTags.push(drug[row][tagColumn]);
  }

  return( availableTags );
}
```

I have tried creating the appended values with the same name/id/and class, but nothing seems to be working. A bonus question would also be: when a user goes to submit the form, how do I capture all of the appended boxes' values?

Comment: you should never have form inputs without id/name and never two with the same id/name. you're building them in a loop, just call them `'txtStuff' + count` or similar.

Comment: What are you appending the units too?  It should be an html page.  But all of your code looks like it's on the server.  Or perhaps I should ask you to identify which is server code and which is client side browser code?  And I would give the inputs id's.

Comment: @Cooper boxes are being appended on html page getAvaliableTags is gs code and getUnits and success handler are js

Comment: I don't see where you're using HtmlService at all.  Anyway, I have example that's somewhat similar to what you are trying to do using a dialog.  Take a look.  This isn't the easiest way to create Javascript so I usually keep it pretty simple.  But it will give you a prompt and you respond with the names of your text boxes all separated by forward slashes.  It will create the modeless dialog and you can fill them in and hit submit and the names and values will be appended to the active sheet.

Comment: i did not include the doGet or include functions in my sample script

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and be sure to take a close look at [mcve].

Comment: all that is needed for this problem is the js side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203628/discussion-between-samdaily34-and-cooper).

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a short example of adding textboxes to a dialog and submitting the data back to a spreadsheet**

Run addTextBoxestoADialog().  Give it the names of the textboxes separated by forward slash.  Like this: name1/name2/name3 and then it will build the form.  You can fill in the values and hit submit and the names and values will be appended to the active sheet.

Code.gs:

```
function addTextBoxestoADialog() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var resp=ui.prompt("Adding Text Boxes to a Dialog","Enter unique names of text boxes separate by forward slash /.",ui.ButtonSet.OK );
  var tA=resp.getResponseText().split('/');
  var html='<html><head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>';
  html+='<script>function fileUploadJs(frmData){google.script.run.upLoadForm(frmData);}</script></head><body>';
  html+='<form id="myForm">';
  for(var i=0;i<tA.length;i++) {
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<br /><input type="text" value="%s" name="%s" /> %s',i+1,tA[i],tA[i]);//added default values
  }
  html+=Utilities.formatString('<input type="hidden" value="%s" name="NameArray" />',tA.join('~~~'));
  html+='<br /><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="fileUploadJs(this.parentNode)" />';
  html+='</form></body></html>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  ui.showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Adding TextBoxes");
}

function upLoadForm(theForm) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(theForm));
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var nA=theForm.NameArray.split('~~~');
  for(var i=0;i<nA.length;i++) {
    sh.appendRow([nA[i],theForm[nA[i]]]);
  }
}
```